# Sorting Based on a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

Project is located at

http://code-dojo.herokuapp.com/

and

https://github.com/TylerSangster/Code-Dojo

I have a resource review site with the following models.

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :reviews


class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :resource
```

I have added resource sorting by name, created at, and cost. I would also like to sort by the highest reviewed resource.

How can I create a sort by review.score ?

EDIT
resource controller

```
  def index
    @resources = Resource.where(status: true).includes([:providers, :subjects, :formats, :reviews])
    @resources = @resources.tagged_with(params[:tag]) if params[:tag]
    @resources = @resources.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    @resources = @resources.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)


    respond_with @resources
  end
```

private methods

```
  def sort_column
    Resource.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

application.rb

```
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
  end
```

index.html.erb

<%= sortable "name" %>

```
  <li><div class="btn btn-default"><%= sortable "created_at", "Most Recent" %></div></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Highest Rated", resources_path, class:"btn btn-default" %></li>
  <li><div class="btn btn-default"><%= sortable "cost" %></div></li>
```

Comment: If each resource has many reviews, how do you want to order them by `review.score` since each review has many of them? By sum perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to sort a set of resources based upon their review scores, and there are many review scores per resource, then a means of evaluating them needs to be determined. To do this, one could think about what the scores mean and why they would be sorted for the user.

A logical choice might be to sum the review scores of a resource to create an aggregate score for the resource. It would work like this (assuming `@resources` is a collection of Resource active records):

```
@resources.sort_by( &:aggregate_score )
```

The highest rated would be the last element:

```
highest_score_resource = @resources.sort_by( &:aggregate_score ).last
```

In the Resource model, define `aggregate_score`:

```
def aggregate_score
  self.reviews.select { |r| r.score }.sum(&:score)
end
```

If you know the scores are never `nil`, then you could do:

```
def aggregate_score
  self.reviews.sum(&:score)
end
```

If you decide that there's some other means you want to use to compute an aggregate score for the resource, you change the algorithm in `aggregate_score`.

Comment: One last thing I want to turn this into a button  how would you do this?

Comment: @Tyler, glad this helps. The button is a whole other thing. Do you want something to happen in the view when the button is clicked?

Comment: @mbatch Yes, I currently have it sorting with buttons for resource name,create_at and cost. I need to include one more highest rated review. With your help I sorted by default the highest rated. I am going to include my index action from the resource controller.

Comment: @Tyler, I'm not sure how you're currently doing it, but I would suppose it could look like the way you do it for the other two cases, `create_at` and `cost`.

Comment: I put the code in my first post. I always had a db column to sort with.

Comment: @Tyler You could try making the "rating" (aggregate score) a virtual attribute. Add `attr_accessor :aggregate_score` to the Resource model.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need order method of ActiveRecord class

```
Review.order("score")
```

There is an [article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) that might help you too.

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:**

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ordered, :order => "some_col DESC"
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources
end

review.resources # uses the default ordering
review.resources.ordered # uses the "some_col DESC" ordering
```

Comment: I need to order resources based on Reviews.

Comment: oh sorry I did not understand the question correctly, check my edited answer... this should be usable, please click accept button if so :)

Comment: and here is an [official guide about scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)... might be helpful too

Comment: @Tyler, I think you still need to define how to handle ordering when a Resource has multiple reviews, each with a score. How do you want to aggregate them to form a sortable attribute?

Comment: @mbratch I am not sure on how I Should do this.